# Spring Boot,ActiveMQ, Modify Broker Url

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I had some problems When I use **Spring boot(1.2.5)** with **ActiveMQ(5.11.1)**.

When I set below value in sping boot's application.properties

> spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616

**It works well**.

When I set another value like below:

> spring.activemq.broker-url=stomp://localhost:61613

It throws :

> Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=localhost}

Or like

> spring.activemq.broker-url=mqtt://localhost:1883

Also Throws

> Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=localhost}

Full exception Info:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.jms.config.internalJmsListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=localhost, maximumConnections=1000, wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600}
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:770)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at cn.vamos.Application.main(Application.java:39)
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=localhost, maximumConnections=1000, wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600}
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:273)
at org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.start(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.java:167)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
... 13 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=localhost, maximumConnections=1000, wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600}
at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:319)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:332)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:305)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:245)
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:413)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.establishSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:381)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.doStart(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:285)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStart(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:209)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:270)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=localhost, maximumConnections=1000, wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600}
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:122)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:64)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:317)
... 24 more
```

A part of ActiveMq Start Informations like below:

```
INFO | KahaDB is version 5
INFO | Recovering from the journal ...
INFO | Recovery replayed 480 operations from the journal in 0.066 seconds.
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.11.1 (localhost, ID:LBDZ-20120706QF-18491-1437644294931-0:1) is starting
INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://LBDZ-20120706QF:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector openwire started
INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://LBDZ-20120706QF:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector amqp started
INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://LBDZ-20120706QF:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector stomp started
INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://LBDZ-20120706QF:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector mqtt started
INFO | Listening for connections at ws://LBDZ-20120706QF:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector ws started
```

Pom.xml about activeMQ:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-mqtt</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any one can help me out? Thans a lot !

Comment: Very late help here but the problem isn't with `Spring Boot` it's that you need to configure the [BrokerService](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerService.html) in your `WebSocketConfig`

Comment: @EddieB,Very late thanks!

Comment: You're Very Welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're getting sound like the ones you'd get if you tried to use STOMP for a broker-to-broker networkConnection (see section #1 in the middle of http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/activemq-users/201502.mbox/%3C1424962402912-4692106.post@n4.nabble.com%3E); are you sure that spring.activemq.broker-url is how you're supposed to set the URL at which the broker is listening?  (After all, your log shows that you're listening on a number of protocols/ports already, which doesn't seem like it's being controlled by that property.)